# Create point data from the attributes of other point layers

Tags: qgis

I'd like to create a shapefile point layer (for later interpolation) from the attributes of some other point/line layers I have. Basically I've created a natural neighbour grid of stress direction (I'm a geologist), and converted that to a rather dense shapefile point layer, with an attribute describing direction of stress (angle/180) at each point.

I then have a shapefile line layer, which I've used the field calculator to create a 'direction' (angle/360) for each line segment.

I'm interested in the difference between the direction of each line segment and the direction of stress. Ideally I'd like to be able to create a point layer, with a point at each place the stress grid overlaps (of is near to) a line segment, the attribute I want being the difference between line direction and stress direction at each point. The final output I'm after being a natural neighbour interpolation (I can do this bit) of the angle between my lines and the stress direction.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  If you place a question mark somewhere within your question what you are trying to ask should become more obvious.